# Code using `extern template auto` compiles on some optimization levels and fails on others

Tags: c++, templates, extern, auto

I have a template that I do not want to be implicitly instantiated for `T=int`. Therefore, I declare it as extern for `T=int` (I do **not** want a specialization). I do this so I can instantiate the template (meta-)code in a different file, which will avoid unnecessary recompilation of `foo<int>()` if only `main()` changes, but not `foo()`.
This is my code:

test.cpp:

```
template<class T>
auto foo()
{
    return;
}

extern template auto foo<int>();

int main()
{
    foo<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

As expected, this code does not compile if I use `g++ test.cpp`. However, when I compile it using `g++ -O test.cpp`, it compiles successfully.

I can't seem to find out why this is the case. I'm suspecting it has to do with this paragraph from [CPP-reference: function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_instantiation):

> Explicit instantiation declarations do not suppress the implicit instantiation of inline functions, auto-declarations, references, and class template specializations.

This suspicion comes from the fact that this program:

test2.cpp

```
template<class T>
void foo()
{
    return;
}

extern template void foo<int>();

int main()
{
    foo<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

where `auto` was substituted by `void`, does not compile for any optimization level (as it should).

But my understanding of optimization levels thus far was that any optimization level satisfies the standard, so even if `test.cpp` is supposed to compile because of the quoted paragraph, it should compile on any optimization level.

Is my understanding of optimization levels wrong, or might this be a bug in g++? My g++ version is 12.2.0.

Thanks for any help!

(I also found a similar example that compiles using `-O2`, but fails to do so on `-O`. Left it out for brevity so far, let me know if it would be helpful.)

Comment: gcc has lots of non-standard extensions enabled by default, but yes optimizations, in principle, must all not alter the observable behavior as specified in the standard

Comment: How can I disable these non-standard extensions? Specifying a C++ standard through e.g. `--std=c++20` does not seem to change anything.

Comment: `-pedantic-errors` iirc, though afaik this isnt sufficient to disable all extensions.

Comment: *"I do not want to be implicitly instantiated for T=int. Therefore, I declare this specialization as extern"* - ¿Why not add a static_assert or mark specialization deleted?

Comment: [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/o3P6q3e6M) has the same behaviour, a `static_assert` is more likely to be what you actually want to use https://godbolt.org/z/4qGxs31hG

Comment: I do want to instantiate the specialization, only in a different compilation unit so it is not recompiled every time I compile my main, even though it does not change.

Comment: To know what `auto` is, isn't instantiation needed?

Comment: The compiler flags are a red-herring. The code does not declare an `int` specialization since the `template` keyword is missing angle brackets.

Comment: @Jarod42 That is probably the problem, now I think I understand the paragraph from CPP reference. Thanks! Still should not work on any optimization level though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a function template has a deduced return type, the idea of preventing implicit instantiation doesn't make sense. It's impossible for the compiler to even determine whether a function call is well-formed, unless it knows the return type. And that means it must instantiate the body here in this translation unit.

According to [[temp.inst]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#1), when a function has a deduced return type, it is not considered to be a *declared specialization* even though it has an explicit instantiation declaration. Only declared specializations can have their implicit instantiation suppressed.

So, if you want to suppress implicit instantiation, you must avoid the deduced return type.

The reason why you see different behaviour depending on the optimization level has to do with [[temp.explicit]/13](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#13):

> [...] An entity that is the subject of an explicit instantiation declaration and that is also used in a way that would otherwise cause an implicit instantiation in the translation unit shall be the subject of an explicit instantiation definition somewhere in the program; otherwise the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

This is very similar to what happens when you declare a function and don't define it, but you do odr-use the function: you violate the one-definition rule and the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. It might compile and link anyway, most likely because the compiler has either inlined the call or optimized it out entirely.

In your case, `-O` has probably caused the compiler to optimize out the call to `foo<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the posted code: 1) the `extern` declaration does not declare a specialization and 2) you cannot use an `auto` return type before it is defined.

If you add empty angle brackets to the `template` keyword in the `extern` declaration, the compiler will interpret it as a specialization: `template<> auto foo<int>();` instead of `extern template auto foo<int>();`, the latter of which is not the declaration of a specialization.

After this change, the compiler will complain about an `auto` return type being used before the function is defined.

The following code compiles, but fails to link since I did not provide a definition of the specialization.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::cout, std::endl;

template<class T>
void foo() {
    return;
}

template<> void foo<int>();

// template<>
// auto foo<int>() {
//     return;
// }

int main() {
    foo<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

Just to clarify a very obscure technical point that this question exposed.

This declaration,

```cpp
extern template void foo<int>();
```

indicates to the compiler that `foo<int>` is instantiated in a different compilation unit so it is not necessary to compile it in the current compilation unit. However, it may choose to compile it in the current compilation unit and for very simple functions that are inlined with optimization turned on likely will (and clang and gcc clearly do).

This declaration,

```cpp
template<> void foo<int>();
```

declares a specialization. It can may or may not be in a different compilation unit and everything will work as expected as long as it is instantiated somewhere.

So, this code, maybe surprisingly, compiles and runs with the desired results (if linked with another file with the definition of `foo<int>()`).

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::cout, std::endl;

template<class T>
void foo() {
    static_assert(not std::is_same_v<T, int>);
    return;
}

template<> void foo<int>();
extern template void foo<int>();

// template<>
// auto foo<int>() {
//     return;
// }

int main() {
    foo<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

Some other compilation unit,

```cpp
template<class T> void foo();

template<> void foo<int>() {
    return;
}
```

### *Another Update*

I have misunderstood the question. The goal is to use the instantiation of `foo()` from a different compilation unit. There is no element of specialization involved.

If you only declare the `template`, everything will work as expected.

```cpp
template<class T>
void foo();

int main() {
    foo<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

However, this precludes using `auto`, such as,

```cpp
template<class T>
auto foo();

int main() {
    foo<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

And, attempting to include the definition and explicitly suppressing the instantiation in the current compilation unit,

```cpp
template<class T>
auto foo() {
    return;
}

extern template auto foo<int>();

int main() {
    foo<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

doesn't work because the `extern` is only a suggestion for the compiler not to instantiate the template in the current compilation unit.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part, I do not want a template specialization. I want to provide the definition for the extern template declaration in a different file, by simply explicitly instantiating the template (meta-)code through `template auto foo<int>();`.

Comment: Yes, and when I provide a definition in a different compilation unit and link, it all works as expected.

Comment: How does the definition look then? I want `foo<int>()` to work the same as the generic `foo<T>()`, just that it is instantiated in a different compilation unit.
As far as I have seen, the code you provided does not address this, as it does not involve explicit instantiation.

Comment: I am sorry, I have been misunderstanding you question. You don't want a specialization, but to use the instantiation from a different compilation unit. Ok, let me update my answer again.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but IIRC `extern` is not just a suggestion. It is - technically speaking - not standard-compliant that linking works on higher optimization, but since the template has to be instantiated in order for `auto` to be deduced (thank you @Jarod42 for pointing this out), gcc decides to just use it anyways, since throwing it away just to throw an error is probably not efficient (which is the whole point of using `extern`).